# In Ruby FFI when I return a dynamically allocated string should I free it?

Tags: ruby, ffi

I have the following function in C

```
char* strfunc()
{
   char* ch=calloc(100,1);
   strcpy(ch,"hello");
   return ch;
}
```

Then in ruby I have

```
module XYZ
   extend FFI::Library
   ffi_lib "mylib.so"
   attach_function :strfunc, [] , :string
end
```

Should I import free to free memory allocated to the string returned or will Ruby GC do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nor FFI, nor ruby GC will free it automatically, because, they does not know it's malloc'd and not just some static memory.

You should free it manually with libc's `free()` call. Please, reference to this ticket https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/467 for examples.

Answer (score 0):

My GUESS would be that ruby GC will take care of it.  However, it's really easy to see for yourself.  You can use [GC.start](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/GC.html#method-c-start) and [GC.stat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/GC.html#method-c-stat) to determine if the objects you are allocating will get freed when GC runs.